# Handling WaterfallSteps of a dialog Bot Framework V4 - Alexa Adapter

Tags: botframework, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to integrate chatbot developed using MS bot framework V4 in NodeJS to the Alexa Channel. I am successful to an extent by referring to the GitHub repo [Bot Builder Community - Alexa adapter library](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-js/tree/master/libraries/botbuilder-adapter-alexa).

But I am facing an issue while handling the flow/forwarding to the next waterfall step of Dialog chatbot V4 for an Alexa skill. Is there a way to handle this?

For better understanding I am attaching screenshots as links below:

[image: Waterfall Steps of the dialog]

Waterfall Steps of the dialog

[image: second waterfall step of the dialog]

In the first waterfall step I have a text prompt prompting for an order number, once it is prompted as a voice in Alexa skill and once user say his order number, ideally it should reach at the second waterfall step of the dialog but the dialog is starting from the 1st waterfall step. I guess Alexa is accepting as a new request hence it is starting from beginning but I want it to forward for next waterfall step. How can I achieve this or is there any other way to do this.